# Commit my newly modified code so that it will be patched on the original codebase, and not on top of my last commit?

Tags: git, github, git-commit, git-push, git-reset

I did a git commit followed by git push. After that, I made some code changes and want to commit this code instead. 
But now if I do a git push, the changes will be shown on top of my changes (showing deleted lines from my first commit which never existed in the codebase).

How can I commit my newly modified code x such that it will be patched on the original codebase, and not on top of my last commit (as if it were my first commit)?

Comment: `git commit --amend` then push your code.

Comment: @uditrawat and it fails because your push needs force. And you didn't add a disclaimer about branch sharing. Just in case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided this is a feature branch on which you're working alone

```
# make your last changes, then
git add .
git commit --amend
git push --force origin HEAD
```

Here, `--amend` is the flag asking git to replace last commit with this one in the branch history. That's the reason you need `--force` in the subsequent push.